# Lavatory — US terms used in the 1950s

Tags: single-word-requests, history, feminine

I am trying to find out what would be natural terms to refer to the lavatory in the US in the 1950s. I am specifically interested in how a *woman who was a teenager at that time in a poor working class area of a city* might refer to this in a novel written today.

The reason behind this request is that I am reading [Elena Ferrante’s “My Brilliant Friend”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_Novels) in the original Italian (L’Amica Geniale) in a language class in Britain. The native Italian teacher does not like the English translation, and in particular objects to the use of ‘bathroom’ to translate the Italian ‘cesso’ (on p.89 of the Italian edition). This is in a poor area of Naples, where the apartment blocks, I imagine, had no bathrooms (in the literal British sense of a room with a bath) but just lavatories, perhaps shared and on the landing.

I did live in the Chicago in the early ’70s, and am familiar with ‘john’ and ‘can’ and several other terms one can find on the web (e.g. [here](https://theweek.com/articles/580173/brief-history-lavatory-language)) but wonder what an educated American woman in her 70s might use as a better translation. Obviously New York brownstones are not Naples slums, so I appreciate that there is no exact equivalent. But still, anything other than bathroom!

**Addendum 1**
There has been comments asking for clarification of the meaning of the Italian, *cesso*. Collins English–Italian indicates that it is *currently* a familiar equivalent to the more usual word for lavatory, *gabinetto*, and rather unsatisfactorily translates it as *bog* (Brit) — haven’t heard that in years — and *john* (Am). *Diziario Italiano da un affiliato di Oxford University* (built into iOS) defines it as the Italian, *Latrina* (latrine), and dates it to 1300. Although, as has been pointed out, its contemporary use is to indicate a primitive or dirty lavatory, its use in the book is neutral and secondary — to indicate the facility in use in the apartment block where the author grew up. The reason I dislike *bathroom* is that it brings up the image of a room with a bath, which is quite out of keeping with the poor area of Naples in which the book is set. The lavatory may well have been of the ‘Elephant’s foot’ type, still encountered in Italy today, and its cleanliness will have depended on social standards of hygiene etc. It would certainly have been different from a US lavatory of the time (except perhaps in poor rural areas) and it would not have had a bath in it. However, the question is what would the US equivalent have been called.

**Addendum 2**
The British (non-dialect) answer would almost certainly be *lavatory*, and I am starting to wonder whether this is really so ‘un-American’. After all, this is the term used in US airplanes/aeroplanes.

Comment: I can well understand why the Italian teacher in Britain does not like the translation of "bathroom". No one in Britain (other than an American ex-patriate) would refer to a "bathroom" to mean anything other than a room which contains a bath.

Comment: @WS2 — Of course. But one should, I think, accept that this is a US English translation. The question is whether children in US cities in the 50s would have used the term bathroom, and whether there is a better US English word or description for what was probably nearer to an outhouse.

Comment: The Italian term “cesso” is still commonly used in Italian for poor, dirty toilets. Outhouse is the AmE sense.

Comment: ngrams for American English from 1940-1960: ( [use the ~](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use+the+lavatory%2Cuse++the+bathroom%2Cuse++the+restroom%2Cuse++the+toilet&year_start=1940&year_end=1960&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuse%20the%20lavatory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuse%20the%20bathroom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuse%20the%20restroom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cuse%20the%20toilet%3B%2Cc0) )

Comment: and ( [go to the ~](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=go+to+the+lavatory%2Cgo+to+the+bathroom%2Cgo+to+the+restroom%2Cgo+to+the+toilet%2C&year_start=1940&year_end=1960&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20the%20lavatory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20the%20bathroom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20the%20restroom%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgo%20to%20the%20toilet%3B%2Cc0) )

Comment: @Jim - I don’t think it is the question of which definition was most popular but which definition used in the ‘50s conveyed the idea of “cesso”.

Comment: Could you add some information, maybe a picture, of what a "Cesso" is?

Comment: @Jim — At the moment no. A film/TV series of the novel is shortly to be released, but I don't know whether it will include the scene in question as it involves the discovery of menstrual blood on the girl's knickers. Whether it was a flush or dry toilet is also not clear to me, and whether it was in the house or outside. It did have a mirror.

Comment: Can you take the definition of "cesso" in Italian and translate that to English for us?

Comment: @Jim - this is what a cesso is:  https://www.google.it/search?q=cesso&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=imvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2maf_h9XeAhUGqYsKHRoGCgoQ_AUoAXoECAwQAQ&biw=768&bih=915#imgrc=9eScRXn09RfkQM - https://www.google.it/search?q=cesso&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=imvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2maf_h9XeAhUGqYsKHRoGCgoQ_AUoAXoECAwQAQ&biw=768&bih=915#imgrc=9eScRXn09RfkQM&imgdii=Iffiy-aRRoRiKM -

Comment: "Washroom" and "commode" are slightly more popular than "restroom" in that Ngram view.

Comment: If it is outside, and .. shacklike, it’s (and was) an *outhouse*.

Comment: @WS2 - I'm afraid that you're wrong - as a native BrE speaker in my early 30s, I do tend to call any room with a toilet a "bathroom"... [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bathroom) does agree with you that this is an Americanism. I have no idea, unfortunately, whether I picked it up from my parents' speech or from watching American TV. I never thought I was unusual in calling a restaurant's toilets "the bathroom"...

Comment: For completeness, we should mention "powder room".

Comment: I suspect that the Italian "cesso" is related in etymology to the (US) English "cesspool".

Comment: @HotLicks — Wrong suspect, I think. The Italian dictionary relates it to cessare, to cease/stop, with the significance of 'retire to' ("di cessare nel sign. arc. di 'ritarsi'"). Chambers says the origin of the (British) English cesspool is obscure, but online sources suggest it is related to ['cistern'](https://www.etymonline.com/word/cesspool). I don't think it was ever a latrine to which one 'retired'.

Comment: @David - The term is occasionally (though no doubt increasingly rarely) used in the sense of "outhouse" in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks — It may have also been so used in Britain in that case, as the word is of English, rather than US origin. The reason I was so quick on the draw was that I had thought of the connection you suggested myself, only to find that it was apparently a false association. (I must say the iOS dictionaries you can download are very good — pity that you cannot browse them or search them directly. Just look up a word that you have typed out somewhere or is in an email.)

Comment: Apparently the first episodes of the TV series are on Sky Atlantic on Monday for anyone who subscribes to that. (Not me — wouldn't give a penny to that man.) If you are in Italy you can see it on RAI.

Comment: 'Toilet', meaning a "room, building, or cubicle fitted for people to urinate and defecate in" is the most obvious choice. Use of the word with this meaning was common in the US in the 1950s, and I don't see anything in your question ruling it out. Some reason not to use that?

Comment: @JEL — I've nothing against toilet or anything else. But nobody has suggested it as an answer. If you can support it — even with anecdotal evidence — I'd be happy to read your answer.

Comment: @user067531 — I'm just reading the second volume of the Neapolitan novels and to my surprise I encounter the author's description of the "cesso" in the modern house of her friend after her marriage "Ogni spazio, ogni cosa, era nuova et pulita, ma più di tutto il cesso, che aveva il lavandino, il bidet, la vasca" — "Every room, everything was new and clean, but above all the "cesso", which had a washbasin, a bidet, a bath(tub)". So Ferrante is clearly using the word as a bathroom in the modern (British) sense, although contrasting it to that in her own home. But Nothing to do with my quesition.

Answer (score 1):

My grandmother calls bathrooms in homes a wash closet and for bathrooms in public areas such as: offices, restaurants, theaters, etc.; she calls them washrooms. She was in her early twenties in the 1950's and grew up in a poor area in the outskirts of Chicago.

Comment: Can you explain why this is relevant (e.g. did she live in the US in the 1950s?  Is she from the social background matching the question?).  Because most of us here don't know her, we can't assess this anecdotal evidence without that context!